# select and then again select distinct values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have 3 columns `questionid`, `replyid` and `userid`.

I want to select all `questionid's from userid where userid is session[userid]`,
And then select distinct `questionid` from it.

Right now I take all those `questionid` belonging to `$_SESSION['user_id']` in an array( and remove duplicates from it) and then
I again pass another query

```
foreach($array as $x)
{
$query="select questionid,replyid,userid from table where questionid=$x"
}
```

But I think that the above steps can be done in query itself(**and the above step is not working also**). I tried below but its not working.
If I try to pass this query then duplicate value still comes:

```
SELECT distinct(questionid),replyid,userid 
from table 
where userid=$_SESSION['user_id']
```

So what should be the query?

```
questionid,replyid,userid

8          ,2     ,45

8          ,3      ,45

9           ,8      ,41
```

But as  `8,2` and `8,3` are in same webpage(one question and two answers), I want to avoid showing duplicate question...

So I was trying the wrong way as I was taking distinct `questionid` and then again selecting `* from table where questionid` was previous one.

But then as @ Mahmoud Gamal suggested I did

```
 SELECT distinct questionid, `answerid`, `userid`
 FROM `table` 
 WHERE  userid='$user'
```

But again I had done the same duplicate thing. So I added `limit 0,1`

```
 SELECT distinct questionid, `answerid`, `userid`
 FROM `table`
 WHERE  userid='$user' 
 LIMIT 0,1
```

Comment: no, but will try now and see, can you show me an example if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the equivalent of the two queries you described in your post:

```
SELECT DISTINCT questionid, replyid, userid 
FROM table 
WHERE questionid IN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT questionid
    FROM table 
    WHERE userid = @user_id
)
```

This will give you `DISTINCT questionid, replyid, userid`. But this isn't by necessary, contains `DISTINCT(questionid)`.

If you are looking for `distinct questionid`, you will end up with a `GROUP BY questionid` with aggregate functions for other two fields `replyid, userid`, like `SUM`, `MAX` or `MIN`.

Comment: Ya it still shows duplicate values, because table is like this (8,2,45) and (8,3,45) and (9,8,41) ..so even if you get disinct questionid(8), the row we get will still be duplicate

Comment: @netuser - Can you please add some sample data that you have and how you would like to be selected from that query.

Comment: @netuser Have you tried `SELECT DISTINCT questionid, replyid, userid ` like in my edit?

Comment: Thankyou, I tried but it was still showing duplicate. But then limit 0,1 solved it...

Comment: It was that I was getting distinct value 8, but then if I select * from table where questionid=8 will again give duplicate. But as questionid and userid are unique,(meaning no questionid is repeated nor is userid), I did limit 0,1...is it best way? It does solve the problem though!

Comment: @netuser - Sorry I can't get it, Can you please edit your question with this new query and also this sample data and explain the problem in more details.

Comment: I have added data and query @Mahmoud gamal